# calling ejb3.0 in action class. application server : websphere7.0 and IDE: RAD7.5

Tags: ejb-3.0, websphere

I have written one stateless session bean and deployed in the server. when i tried to access that particular ejb, it's throwing error.

### Code sample:

TestServiceBeanRemote  : Remore bean
TestServiceBean        : Actual bean

Context context =  new InitialContext();
TestServiceBeanRemote test = (TestServiceBeanRemote)context.lookup("com.test.ejb.TestServiceBean");
test.hello("ejb3.0");

Error :

[5/23/11 14:27:00:250 IST] 0000001b SystemErr     R javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: gopatilbNode01Cell/nodes/gopatilbNode01/servers/server1, name: com.test.ejb.TestServiceBean: First component in name com.test.ejb.TestServiceBean not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]

[5/23/11 14:27:00:250 IST] 0000001b SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4365)

****: Do i need to configure anything in was7.0 ? or do i need to write any xml file for jndi lookup in ejb3.0 ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

The default bindings in WebSphere Application Server are the interface name (e.g., `com.test.ejb.TestService`) and `<app>/<module>/<bean>#<interface>` (e.g., `MyTest.ear/test.jar/TestServiceBean#com.test.ejb.TestService`).  These can be changed during the deploy process or using ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml.  More information is available in the [EJB 3.0 application bindings overview](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html) InfoCenter topic.